# Reading barcodes with manateeworks

Tags: android, barcode

I'm using MANATEE WORKS to read bar codes, 
but when I moved the phone to the left, the image 
of the camera goes down and when I moved the phone 
to the right, the image goes up. 
When I moved the phone up, the 
image of the camera will move to 
the left and when the phone down, 
the image goes to the right.

Examples in: http://manateeworks.com/download
(Andorid)

What can be happening? This has solution?

Comment: can you help me to integrate the sdk sample in you project? it not work for me due to diff package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

Change to:
       // mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);

But not work in Android versions prior to 3.0